# Writing a code to find parallel lines between coordinates (Using C)

Tags: c, geometry

I have a task where I need to read information from a text file in which there are coordinates (x and y) and I need to count how many parallel lines I can create out of these coordinates. I'm not fully sure how to do it. I tried writing my own code with some help of a friend.

The program opens the text file, but gets stuck at: `f = getLines(file);` part, which is why I'm providing complete code. . .

(The [code](http://pastebin.com/41Hrrp1M))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define FILE_PATH "D:\\Task5\\Task5.txt"

//==============================    STRUCTURES

typedef struct {
    char* lines;
    int size;
} FileLines;

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

typedef struct {
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    int slope;
} Line;

//==============================    PROTOTYPES
FILE* getFile();
FileLines getLines(FILE* file);
Point *getPointsFromFileLines(FileLines file);
Point getPointFromString(char* string);
Line *getAllLines(Point* coords,int size);
int countParralelLines(Line* lines, int size);
//==============================    FUNCTIONS

FILE* getFile() {                               // 
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(FILE_PATH,"r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        printf("File opened for reading \n");
    return file;
}

FileLines getLines(FILE *file) {
    char c;
    FileLines f = {0,0};
    int fileSize = sizeof(f.lines)/sizeof(f.lines[0]);
    char *line = 0;
    int size = sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]);

    while(!feof(file)) {
        while(c != '\n'){
            c = getc(file);
            line = realloc(line, ++size);
            line[size-1] = c;
        }
        f.lines = realloc(f.lines, ++fileSize);
        f.lines[fileSize-1] = *line;
    }
    return f;
}

Point *getPointsFromFileLines(FileLines file) {
    Point* p = 0;
    int i;
    int size = (sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]));
    for(i = 0; i < file.size; i++) {
        p = realloc(p, (size*(i+1)));
        getPointFromString((char *)file.lines[i]);
    }
    return p;
}

Point getPointFromString(char* string) {
    Point p = {0,0};
    while(*string != '\n') { //
        if(*string == 'x') {
            do {
                if(isdigit(*string))
                    break;
                string++;
            } while(*string); //
            p.x = (int) strtol(string, &string, 10);

        }
        if(*string == 'y') { //
            do {
                if(isdigit(*string))
                    break;
                string++;
            } while(*string); //
            p.y = (int) strtol(string, &string, 10);
        }
    }
    return p;
}

Line *getAllLines(Point* coords,int size) {
    int number_of_lines = factorial(size);
     Line l[number_of_lines];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++) {
        for(j = i; j < number_of_lines; j++) {
            l[j].p1 = coords[i];
            l[j].p2 = coords[j+1];
        }
    }
    return l;
}

int factorial(unsigned int i) {
    if(i <= 1)
        return 1;
    return (i + factorial(i-1));
}

int countParralelLines(Line* lines,int size) {
    int count;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size; i++) {
            if(i==j) continue;
            if(lines[i].slope == lines[j].slope)
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

//==============================    MAIN PART

int main()
{
    FileLines f = {0,0};
    FILE *file;

    file = getFile();

    printf("1 \n");

    f = getLines(file);

    printf("2 \n");

    Point *coords = 0;
    coords = getPointsFromFileLines(f);

    printf("3 \n");

    int size = sizeof(coords)/sizeof(coords[0]);
    int possible_lines = factorial(size);
    Line lines[possible_lines];
    memcpy(lines, getAllLines(coords, size), (sizeof(lines)*sizeof(lines[0])));

    printf("4 \n");

    int count = countParralelLines(lines, possible_lines);
    printf("count: %i", count);

    return 0;
}
```

For this task I'm supposed to use "structures, pointers and dynamic memory".

Text file (Task5.txt) contents:

```
x: 10, y: 15
x: 8, y: -5
x: 85, y: 156
x: 46, y: 67
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow: please read this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to work."* Sorry, but that is not sufficient problem description. Also don't simply link code, read on how to provide [mcve].

Comment: 1) `sizeof(f.lines)/sizeof(f.lines[0])` and `sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0])` and so on are wrong.

Comment: `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` gives you the number of elements if `x` is an array, but it doesn't work if `x` is a pointer.

Comment: In `getLines`, the first iteration of `while (c != '\n')` occurs before `c` has been initialized.

Comment: The number of possible lines is _N_ choose 2, where _N_ is the number of points. This is equal to _N_ * (_N_ - 1) / 2, or _N_! / ((_N_ - 2)! * 2!).

Answer (score 1):

sample of Read Points from file.
like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

Point *getPointsFromFile(FILE *fp, size_t *n){
    int x, y;
    Point *p = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    while(2 == fscanf(fp, " x : %d , y : %d", &x, &y)){
        Point *temp = realloc(p, ++size * sizeof(*p));
        if(!temp){
            perror("realloc at getPointsFromFile");
            free(p);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        p = temp;
        p[size-1] = (Point){ .x = x, .y = y};
    }
    //rewind(fp);
    *n = size;
    return p;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("Task5.txt", "r");
    size_t n = 0;
    Point *points = getPointsFromFile(fp, &n);
    fclose(fp);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", points[i].x, points[i].y);
    free(points);
    return 0;
}
```